# Displacement vs Time graph

Tags: graphs

I want to draw a displacement vs time graph of two runners running around a circle track of unit length so that it looks like the picture below in which one runner is running at speed 1 and another at speed 3.
 [image: displacement vs time graph]
.

I know I could do this by putting in every line separately but I'd rather just do it in one go using some clever method so that putting in runners of high speed wouldn't involve plotting a lot of lines. I have no experience in doing graphs as I never use them in my research.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish that, here is one of them. Big thanks to albert for explaining the question to me!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand{\Runner}[2][]{
\addplot[no marks,thick,samples=2*#2+1,#1] {0.25*(1-cos(#2*x*360))};
\node[anchor=south,#1] at ({1/(2*#2)},0.5) {#2};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[width=12cm,axis lines*=left,domain=0:1]
  \Runner{1};
  \Runner[blue]{3};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is something along the lines you are asking in the comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand{\Runner}[2][]{
\addplot[no marks,thick,samples=2*#2+1,#1] {0.25*(1-cos(#2*x*360))};
\node[anchor=south,#1] at ({1/(2*#2)},0.5) {#2};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
myisodd(\x)=mod(int(\x),2);
runner(\x,\y)=0.5*ifthenelse(myisodd(int(2*\y*\x)),1-(2*\y*\x-int(2*\y*\x)),
(2*\y*\x-int(2*\y*\x)));}]
 \begin{axis}[width=12cm,axis lines*=left,domain=0:1]
  \Runner{1};
  \Runner[blue]{3};
  \addplot[red,thick,samples=13] {min(runner(x,3),runner(x,1))};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just the answer OP mentions as something he know: "I know I could do this by putting in every line separately but I'd rather just do it in one go using some clever method so that putting in runners of high speed wouldn't involve plotting a lot of lines." but he would like probably something like a for loop depending on the number of 'periods'.

Comment: note color of  '1' should be black as it belongs to the '1 period' line.

Comment: @albert Well, sure, *if* this is the interpretation of the OP's question. But how do you arrive at this interpretation.

Comment: I quoted the text from his question and from the word "speed" I got to the "periods" idea.

Comment: albert and marmot. Thank you both for your comments. And marmot for your answer. Albert you were right I was able to write it like Marmot did originally but the edited version is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. 

Can I get some help to understand how this code works. In particular
\newcommand{\Runner}[2][]{
\addplot[no marks,thick,samples=2*#2+1,#1] {0.25*(1-cos(#2*x*360))};}
 
\newcommand makes a new command, I understand this. Can you explain why you have [2][] and then what the #2 and #1 are filled in by.
Also what does samples do in the \addplot?

Comment: @AnAspiringMathematician The first argument, `#1` is an option, which is by default empty. But if you give it a value, as in  `\Runner[blue]{3};`, it allows you to add an optional argument like the color.

Comment: Thanks @marmot, that really helps. Is there a way of highlighting the line which is closest to the time axis as t moves from 0 to 1. That is I want to highlight the runner who is closest to the starting point as time progresses. Again I could plot each line individually but like with the solution above I would like to be able to easily change the speeds without having to re-plot everything.

Comment: @AnAspiringMathematician I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean. What does "highlight" mean? And you want to highlight the slowest runner? That is, I do not understand "I want to highlight the runner who is closest to the starting point as time progresses".

Comment: Sorry I'll try explain better. I would like to be able to add a third plot which runs along the line l:=min (runner 1, runner 2). So it will run alone the smaller of the blue or black line in the example above as t runs from 0 to 1. Does that make sense? 

If I was dealing with linear functions such as 2*x+2 and -3*x+2.5 I know I can do something like \addplot[draw=red,domain= 0:1]{min(2*x+2,-3*x+2.5)}; 
and this works perfect but not sure how to do it with the above functions. In particular since to get the shape we wanted we only took a small sample of the points (2#2+1).

Comment: @AnAspiringMathematician I added something along the lines you suggest. (I had to rewrite the `isodd` function because it is not yet implemented in fpu, which pgplots uses by default.)  Note, however, that by the rules of this site, I am not supposed to answer additional requests. Therefore, I would like to ask you to make any other request in form of a new question. Questions are free, after all. And it is perfectly fine to use the code from this answer in your question.

Comment: @marmot What you added is perfect. I could have never come up with something like that. I did not realize that was a rule of the site so thank you for letting me know I will keep that mind in future. Thank you again for all your help.